# Android: Nested Linearlayouts will not display a grid of buttons, Matching parent

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I have an app under construction. In one of the sub-menus I have a need for generic display of buttons, and therefor I want to make an activity that can display the given number of needed buttons.

I have succesfully made this happen, programmatically, but I want the total grid of buttons to fill up the entire parent they are placed in, which happens to be 3/4 of a landscape screen. The number of buttons varies from 16-38.!

I have also succesfully made this happen with other grids of buttons, in xml, with weight values, and match_parent values of entries.

When I assign buttons or rows the match_parent value programatically, it occupies the entire parent layout, not sharing it like i expect it to do, even though they have the same weight value of 1.0f

The relevant code follows below. I would like to post images as well, but I have not the reputation to do so.

`LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_custom_draw);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

```
    int columns = Math.min(6, 4+category); //sets number of buttons per row to 4-6

    for (int i = 0; i < 4+category; i++) {
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
```

android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); 
//the line above is the line that fills up the entirety of the linearlayout, even though there are more entries, unlike my xml-defined attempts.
            row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            row.setWeightSum(1.0f);
            if(i%2 == 0){
                row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_red_backgr_color));
            }

```
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            int index = (i*columns)+j;
            if(formations.size() > index){
                Button btnTag = new Button(this);
                btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                btnTag.setText(formations.get(index).getName());
                btnTag.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black_overlay));    
                btnTag.setId(formations.get(index).getId());
                row.addView(btnTag);
            }
        }

        layout.addView(row);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use TableLayout. Each Row will enforce the entire elements to match the parent with the same wights. You can control number of Buttons into each Row programatically with counter. Loop for end of Counter adding your buttons then add new Table Row

```
TableLayout tbl=new TableLayout(context);//create table
TableRow tr=new TableRow(context);//create table row
tr.addView(view);//add your button instead of the view
tbl.addView(tr);//add the row into the Table
```

In the XML file

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/keypad"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:stretchColumns="*">
<TableRow>
    <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_1" android:text="@string/_1"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_2" android:text="@string/_2"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_3" android:text="@string/_3"></Button>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I will give it a go. It will probably help to think outside the box a little.

Comment: I was working on something similar to Create a Numpad as a Layout Dialog. I had to put every Three numbers together as a Row. The TableLayout was the solution for that @user1203811

Comment: Not quite working. The TableLayout produces the exact same upper-left oriented table of buttons, which in no way fills up the screen like I want them to. The only difference from the prior solution is that now it does not react to WRAP_CONTENT or MATCH_PARENT at all. It produces the same output no matter what.

Comment: Make the TableLAyout from the XML file then get a reference to it and modify as above. I will edit my answer to explan the XML code for the Table

Comment: @user1203811 check my answer again. Make sure you put this sentense in the XML: android:stretchColumns="*"

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I actually missed the whole xml-code. It's getting pretty late here in Copenhagen. :) Thank you very much. THe buttons are stretched as I want them horizontally, now I guess I only need to put in a stretchRows or something!

Comment: @user1203811 .. never mind :) but don`t forget to vote my answer up if you found it helpful and accept it as the answer by clicking on the Right sign :)

Comment: I will. It only solved my problem in one of two dimensions, but hey, that is well worth a vote. Thank you very much.